# How can I synchronize multiple android devices with my database?

Tags: android, firebase, performance, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a quiz app for Android, I use Google Firebase for my database, the purpose of the game is to ask a question from the players and the person who answers the question first wins the game. At a certain time of the day, the database automatically generates a question and sends it to the participants.

The quiz must be sent at the same time to all connected users, how can I synchronize the submission of the question to all users ?

Comment: Are you using Realtime Database or Firestore? Can you share a screenshot of your database structure and any code that you are using to submit users' responses?

Comment: I will use the firebase realtime database, I wanted to ask how I can send the question to all users at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can [subscribe all the users to a specific topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) when they sign up and you can use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to [send the notification to the topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#build_send_requests).

All users subscribed to the topic should [receive the notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#receive_and_handle_topic_messages).